# SHA hash does not seem to be working correctly

Tags: java, hash, cryptography

I am trying to build a simple password authenticator where passwords that have been hashed using SHA-256 .

I found a couple calculators online  (http://onlinemd5.com/) that hashed "password" to "5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8"

I tried a couple other passwords with expected results.

So I tried to implement a fairly straight forward set of code (or so I thought)

```
String pswd="password";
String storedPswd="5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8";
//first as a byte[]

Arrays.equals(hashWord(pswd),storedPswd.getBytes("UTF-8") );
...
private byte[] hashWord(String word)     {
    try {
        return MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(word.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (Exception e)        {
       throw new BadCredentialsException("Could not hash supplied password", e);
    }
}
```

I also tried without success.

`return storedPswd.toUpperCase().equals(DigestUtils.sha256Hex(password));`

The Apache codec library (v1.10) and Java 1.6 gives me :

```
113459EB7BB31BDDEE85ADE5230D6AD5D8B2FB52879E00A84FF6AE1067A210D3
```

instead of

```
5E884898DA28047151D0E56F8DC6292773603D0D6AABBDD62A11EF721D1542D8
```

What am I missing ??

The Solution (wrong inputs):

updated Test Code:

```
String passwordSHA="5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8";
String complexSHA="8849fb9b221ddec0117e2796d16929179accf3a6012f738e1ed6c11af9cc2081";
@Test
public void testDigest() throws InterruptedException{
    System.out.println("Starting Digest test");
    String complexPassword = "a7$h1UC8";
    try {
        Assert.assertTrue(authenticateUser(complexPassword, complexSHA));
        Assert.assertTrue(authenticateUser("password", passwordSHA));           
        Assert.assertTrue( hashWord(complexPassword).equals(complexSHA) );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.fail();
    }
}
public boolean authenticateUser(String word, String stored) throws Exception {
    String apache2Pswd = hashApache(word);
    System.out.println(apache2Pswd);                
    return stored.equals(apache2Pswd);
}
private String hashApache(String pswd){
    return DigestUtils.sha256Hex(pswd);     
}
public static String hashWord(String word) throws Exception{
    byte[] digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(word.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : digest) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

With Results:

```
Starting Digest test
8849fb9b221ddec0117e2796d16929179accf3a6012f738e1ed6c11af9cc2081
5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8
8849fb9b221ddec0117e2796d16929179accf3a6012f738e1ed6c11af9cc2081
```

Comment: @LaurentiuL. Unless you're using a salt or something similar, the hash value won't change. Hashes are one way functions.

Comment: Indeed. Had something else in mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hashWord` method that you posted is not correct, it does not compile (is this your actual code?); it's not returning a value.

With this:

```
byte[] digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest("password".getBytes("UTF-8"));

for (byte b : digest) {
    System.out.printf("%02x", b);
}
```

I do get the expected output:

`5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8`

The output `113459eb7bb31bddee85ade5230d6ad5d8b2fb52879e00a84ff6ae1067a210d3` is what you get when you calculate the SHA-256 hash over the string `5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8` instead of the original string `password`.

You are calculating the hash over the hex string containing the hash, instead of the hash of the original password.

Comment: oh that was a goof !  Thanks and yes I was testing the wrong inputs

Comment: I will provide the updated test code in the question.

Comment: I modified your code to return:   String hash(String word) using...
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (byte b : digest) {
      sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
  }
  return sb.toString();

Answer (score 1):

An online resource that does not carefully document how it converts user input to binary before hashing is worthless for the purpose of comparing hashes.

It ultimately doesn't matter if your encoding method produces hashes compatible with anything else. What matters is that you get the same hash for the same input consistently (i.e. the hash procedure must be [deterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Hash_function#Determinism)).

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting, but I did look at a couple different sites that have SHA-256 hashing calculators that produced the same results for a couple different texts that I tried and were consistent with items in the database.